# Qt Settings on Mac

Tags: macos, qt, qt4, makefile, qmake

I am trying something new here. I do have a mac laptop, where in I have some changes in the original qt code. I have the qt code compiled and installed on mac laptop. Now I want to migrate the setup to mac Desktop. So, I thought there is no need to install qt again, rather I copied the entire qt installation directory (which has Qt/bin Qt/lib etc).

I did do a ./configure as I need the qmake and moc tools.My changes are nowhere related to these tools. Now I am building one more Qt application, which requires Qt Core. So I have mentioned in the applications pro file as Qt+ = core. But when I build this application in Mac desktop, I do get an error saying

"**Project ERROR: Unknown module (s) in QT: core**".
I am not sure why am I getting this error. I tried to set the PATH variable to **PATH**=/Users/name/Qt/bin:$PATH and also set **QTDIR**=/Users/name/Qt and even
**LD_LIBRARY_PATH**=/Users/name/Qt/lib.

Am I missing out any variable to be set. How to make qt know that qt libraries are already available(copied one's) even if qt is not explicitly installed in system.

Please help.

Regards,
TechTotie.

Comment: I believe, that shared libraries built on another machine will have wrong dependencies install names inside and that's why just copying of Qt libs will not work.

Comment: You are right. But I have changed the dependencies and checked with dependency tool. All are resolved dependencies.